# Add the label/tag "<root>" to XML file

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML file like this:

```
<object>
 <first>23</first>
 <second>43</second>
 <third>65</third>
</object>
<object>
 <first>4</first>
 <second>3</second>
 <third>93</third>
</object>
```

And I'd like add the tag/label `<root>` at the begining of XML file and `</root>` at the end, like this:

```
<root>
 <object>
  <first>23</first>
  <second>43</second>
  <third>65</third>
 </object>
 <object>
  <first>4</first>
  <second>3</second>
  <third>93</third>
 </object>
</root>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Your first 'XML fragement' is not valid XML. You cannot get it loaded in an XML parser. What is producing your first fragment? Maybe you can change the way how it is produced. Valid XML has one root tag, as in your second XML fragment.

Comment: The xml comes to me without tags. 

How could I add tags <root> and </root>

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier than you're making it out to be:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<object>
 <first>23</first>
 <second>43</second>
 <third>65</third>
</object>
<object>
 <first>4</first>
 <second>3</second>
 <third>93</third>
</object>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML("<root>\n" + xml + '</root>')

puts doc.to_xml

# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <root>
# >> <object>
# >>  <first>23</first>
# >>  <second>43</second>
# >>  <third>65</third>
# >> </object>
# >> <object>
# >>  <first>4</first>
# >>  <second>3</second>
# >>  <third>93</third>
# >> </object>
# >> </root>
```

If you don't want the XML declaration:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("<root>\n" + xml + '</root>')

puts doc.to_xml

# >> <root>
# >> <object>
# >>  <first>23</first>
# >>  <second>43</second>
# >>  <third>65</third>
# >> </object>
# >> <object>
# >>  <first>4</first>
# >>  <second>3</second>
# >>  <third>93</third>
# >> </object>
# >> </root>
```